# HTA, VBScript settimeout, update element not working

Tags: vbscript, hta

Scenario: pull the information from a running HTA and update an INPUT field with the information on a updated every 1 second. The concept was to use the INPUT field as a sort of progress bar while working with thousands of files (like *12300+* files) so that it did not just sit there and do nothing for near half hour!  The end result does not error, but the INPUT field remains empty.

Here is my code (I know it is "dirty" but I was using only for a test):

```
<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=8; IE=7' />

<html>
<head>
<hta:application id=oHTA 
border=none 
caption=no 
contextmenu=no 
innerborder=yes 
scroll=no 
showintaskbar=no 
/>

<style> 
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

img{width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;position:absolute;}
div{z-index:1;position:absolute;color:black;top:80%;width:100%;}
input{width:20%;color:red;background:transparent;}
</style>
</head>


<body style='text-align:center;background:black;'  >
<div>
<button id=click>Click</button><br>
</div>
<input type=text id=myinput />




<script language="vbscript">

mm=self.location.pathname
curdir = split(mm,"\")
for x =0 to ubound(curdir)
settimeout "updater(curdir(x))",10000
next

sub click_onclick
self.close
end sub

function updater(xx)
set ii = document.getelementbyid("myinput")
ii.value=xx
end function
</script>
```

Comment: Running your code as is will result in "Error: Subscript out of range: 'x'". Maybe you have an On Error Resume Next in your test code? Anyhow, settimeout creates an event that runs every x milliseconds (10 seconds in your case). It's not going to work to put settimeout inside a for loop. Think asynchronous. Your current code is attempting to show one level of your path every 10 seconds. Is that what you want? I'm not sure that will be useful as a progress meter. What are you doing with each file? Maybe the progress display could show what file name is currently being processed.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I ended up doing this a different way, got all the bugs out, and have a fully functional HTA! The code itself is extensive and I haven't nearly the amount of characters for the whole thing in the comments section, and would not know how to enter it in any case.  Again, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

As LesFerch had mentioned, I did end up showing the file name that is being processed as well as a functional progress bar. There is too much code to enter the entire HTA contents here but this would give you a decent idea. The whole code is over 1000 lines as I included a Base64 encoded image. Essentially it was a test to rename mp3 files as such: find an entry of ", The" or ", A", remove said entry, add "The " or "A " to the beginning of the respective section whether it be artist or title. As it I have over 14000 MP3s, the code I originally made which worked very well, left the end user (in this case me!) wondering if it was still running. Today, that question is answered!  The code is still ugly and I am sure it could be relieved of alot of dead space, but I am proud.

```
    <body style='text-align:center;background:black;'>
    
    <input type=text id="myinput" value=""  />
    <div style="width:100%;top:10px;text-align:center;" id="myDiv2"></div>
    <div id="myDiv" style="font-size:32px;">
    </div>
    <div style="top:10%;left:0;width:100%;"><h2>TheA: The File Fixer</h2></div>
    <button id="myButton" onclick="killvid()" >Close</button>
    <button id="myAbout" onclick="bignews()" style="left:10%;">About</button>
    <button id="myStart" onclick="startproc()" style="left:43%;">Start</button>    
    
    function myTime(xt)
                    set ws = createobject("wscript.shell")
                    xtr=0
                    do until xtr > xt
                    xtr = xtr+1
                    ws.Run "ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1", 0, true
                    loop
        end function
        
        
        
            function updater(xx,yy)
                set ii = document.getelementbyid("myinput")
                if len(ii.value) < 70 then
                ii.value= ii.value & "|"
                else
                ii.value =""
                end if
                myTime(.25)     
            end function

function startproc()
    window.moveto -19999, -19999
    set s = document.getelementsbytagname("BUTTON")
    for each b in s
    b.style.display = "none"
    next
    set  s = nothing
            on error resume next
    
            str = document.location.pathname
            set ws = createobject("wscript.shell") 
            set fs = createobject("scripting.filesystemobject") 
'Open the BrowseForFolder dialog 
        
                Set a2 = sa.BrowseForFolder( 0, "Select Folder",1,&h11&)
                    sp = a2.Self.Path
    window.moveto screen.width / 2 - 900, screen.height /2 - 500
                        if err.number>0 then 
    
                        set mb = document.getelementbyid("myButton")
                        set md = document.getelementbyid("myDiv")
                        md.innertext="Nothing ventured, Nothing gained!" &vbcrlf & "Please exit this window!"
                        mb.style.display="block"
exit function

'more of the function excerpted

if bfn <> dd then
                fs.copyfile file.path, replace(file.path,bfn,dd),1
                rrr = rrr+1
                    if instr(bfn,rr) then
                    fs.deletefile file.path
                md.innertext = "Renaming " & bfn & " to " &vbcrlf & _
                dd & vbcrlf & "Processing " & dtx & " files." & vbcrlf &_
                "Please wait..."
                    elseif instr(bfn,ss) then
                    fs.deletefile file.path
                dtx = dtx-1
                md.innertext = "Renaming " & bfn & " to " &vbcrlf & _
                dd & vbcrlf & "Processing " & dtx & " files." & vbcrlf &_
                "Please wait..."
                    END IF

                updater bfn,dd  
                end if
end function
```

Comment: Sounds interesting. Maybe post it on GitHub?

Comment: I'll have to research that as well. I have been writing vbscript for the better part of 14 years, but it was only ever for personal use. All of these forums are new to me.  I did all of my learning on W3C until they removed almost everything about VBScript.  I've heard that it is deprecated and moratorium, but it is too easy to configure and phenomenally easy to write.  Some adage here about Old Dogs.. but whatever.  I will look into Git Hub.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool. If you'd like to send me a copy for feedback/streamlining, you can find my contact info on GitHub.